# Calling .NET/C# from R

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, r

I'd like to use an API from R that is only available in .NET.  Is there a standard method that can be used to call .NET C# code from R?  If so, how can I do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another option that readers of this discussion might consider is the [rClr package](https://github.com/jmp75/rClr), which I have been working on for a couple of years to access arbitrary .NET code from R. It is a sibling of [R.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET/) which, conversely, is a way to access R from .NET.

To give a flavour of the rClr package, the canonical "Hello World" looks like:

```
library(rClr)
clrLoadAssembly('c:/path/to/myassembly.dll')
myObj <- clrNew('MyNamespace.MyClass,MyAssemblyName')
clrCall(myObj, 'SayHelloWorld')
```

Feedback and suggestions welcome via the web site.

Comment: Wow - downloaded it and it worked absolutely perfectly!! This package is simply amazing, I look forward to using it a lot in the future. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Does anyone have a simple specific example of above code?

Comment: `library(rClr)
clrLoadAssembly('C:\\__\\TstingRLib\\ClassLibrary1\\bin\\Release\\ClassLibrary1.dll')
yObj <- clrNew('System.System.Text,System')
Type not found: System.System.Text,System
Error in clrNew("System.System.Text,System") : 
  Type:    System.ArgumentException
Message: Could not determine Type from string 'System.System.Text,System'
Method:  System.Object CreateInstance(System.String, System.Object[])
Stack trace:
   at Rclr.ClrFacade.CreateInstance(String typename, Object[] arguments) in ___\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2D63Nz\R.INSTALL1f3c2a50350\rClr\src\ClrFacade\ClrFacade.cs:line 316`

Comment: suggestion for R > 4.0 ?

Answer (score 3):

Exposing the .NET dll as COM dll and then calling a COM object in the dll from R seem to be the only way. And there is a package for it: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rcom/rcom.pdf

If you cannot make a COM dll because it's third-party dll, you can always create a new interface-like .NET dll with COM interface where you can call actual dll.

Comment: To get a list of ProgID's in the system, see http://procbits.com/2010/11/08/get-all-progid-on-system-for-com-automation/