# Is there any way to call .NET's string library from within R?

Tags: c#, .net, r

I'm quite familiar with C# .NET, and I'd like to call functions from .NET's `System.Text` library, such as `.PadLeft()`, `string.Format`, etc.

Does anyone know is this is possible?

Comment: Never used this http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: @kenny This allows calling R from .NET, but what I want is to call .NET from R.

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410528/calling-net-c-from-r?rq=1

Comment: Seems like a really heavy handed approach for something as simple as string padding etc.

Comment: @spender I actually want to call a lot of other .NET functionality from within R, but I've tried to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, as others have mentioned, it isn't easy to call .NET code from R.  Using the `rcom` package [may be viable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410528/calling-net-c-from-r?rq=1), but the intersection of R programmers and C# programmers is pretty small, so few people have tried it.

There are some options if you are willing to tweak your technology stack.

- MATLAB has excellent .NET integration and can do most things that R can do.
- R has pretty good Java integration via the `rJava` package.

If you are happy with a pure-R solution, then the `stringr` package makes string handling pretty painless.  `stringr::str_pad` is the same as C#'s `string.PadLeft` method.  `sprintf`, `format`, `formatC`, and `prettyNum` from base R provide a variety of ways of formatting numbers.  The `scales` package also has several formatting functions.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post has been around for some time, but since searches for answers on StackOverflow are an ongoing affair I thought I'd put another option.

The package rClr is available from https://r2clr.codeplex.com/ , soon to migrate to https://rclr.codeplex.com/. It is possible to call arbitrary .NET code, including string operations:

```
library(rClr)
clrCallStatic('System.String', 'Format', 'Hello, the number is {0}', 42L)
## [1] "Hello, the number is 42"
```

However, since strings, and arrays thereof, are on purpose converted transparently to R character vectors, instance methods such as `PadLeft` are not easily available. A helper class with static methods would do the trick. I'll consider adding facilities for .NET string manipulations in the package if there is interest.

Answer (score 1):

R and .NET are not related in any way. That means that is is not easily possible.

You should simply learn the correct methods to use in R.

Comment: Of course this is possible, but given that I am very familiar with C#, and .NET has a more comprehensive library for dealing with strings, why not?

Comment: Why not write you entire program in .net then?

Comment: @spender Because R has amazing functionality when it comes to dealing with stats, its amazing for interactively exploring data, and I'm doing a www.coursera.com course that teaches data analysis with R.

Comment: Downvoted for "You should simply learn the correct methods to use in R".  That isn't helpful; it's patronising.

Comment: @RichieCotton: It certainly wasn't meant to be or even sound patronising. It is a common and understandable thing for new developers in a certain discipline: They want to use what they already know. But they are on a new platform and therefore should go with the native tools of that platform. Otherwise they will never truly understand that new platform and benefit from its full potential. BTW: Thanks for leaving a comment regarding your downvote, I appreciate that!

Comment: @Richie Cotton I understand where you're coming from - its good to learn the features of a new platform. And I certainly will do when it comes to something as simple as strings. However, I actually want to call a lot of other custom .NET functionality from R, but I restricted the question to strings to keep everything simple.