# Returning Datatable to R from C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, r, datatable, rclr

I'm trying to call a .NET DLL file from [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) and return a Datatable.

This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410528/calling-net-c-from-r) shows how to call .NET from R and that works, but I can't find any documentation on how to return data (apart from simple values like a string):

.NET Method:

```
public DataTable GetDatatable(string parameters)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Dates", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("Strings", typeof(String));
    dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(Double));

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = new DateTime(2014, 1, 23);
    dr[1] = "test";
    dr[2] = 123.45;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    return dt;
}
```

Inside R:

```
> library(rClr)
> clrLoadAssembly('C:/Dev/Sandbox/XYZ/bin/Debug/XYZ2R.dll')
> myObj <- clrNew('XYZ2R.DAL,XYZ2R')
> res = clrCall(myObj,'GetDatatable', "parameter")
> res
```

An object of class "cobjRef" 
Slot "clrobj": 
<pointer: 0x0027f218> 
 
Slot "clrtype": 
[1] "System.Data.DataTable"

> res[0,1] 
>   Error in res[0, 1] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable

[From what I've read](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/360406) it appears I would need to pass in 'by ref' arguments to a params, for example:

```
public void Test(string parameters, params List<string>[] data)
```

Though I am not sure and there isn't any examples of calling .NET methods from R and returning lists. There are a few articles that discuss the opposite.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the currently released package, and using your test method, the following retrieves the items correctly

```
library(rClr)
clrLoadAssembly('c:/tmp/DataTableTest/bin/Debug/DataTableTest.dll')
obj <- clrNew('DataTableTest.Class1')
dataTable <- clrCall(obj, 'GetDatatable', '')
clrReflect(dataTable)
dv <- clrGet(dataTable, 'DefaultView')
clrReflect(dv)
getTableItem <- function(view, rowInd, colInd) {
  dataRowView <- clrCall(view, 'get_Item', as.integer(rowInd))
  clrCall(dataRowView, 'get_Item', as.integer(colInd))
}
getTableItem(dv, 0L, 0L)
getTableItem(dv, 0L, 1L)
getTableItem(dv, 0L, 2L)
```

Over the next few months I'll be working on some syntactic improvements; I take note that DataTable and related classes are a natural sibling to data frames, and will try to offer a more concise syntax for it. Feel free to log detailed feature request at <strike>https://rclr.codeplex.com</strike> https://github.com/jmp75/rClr

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I agree a Datatable to Dataframe is a good idea and a more concise syntax would be good. I will follow your developments. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To inspect methods and properties of .NET objects from R is easy by using the clrReflect method:

**> clrReflect(dataTable)**
$Methods
[1] "AcceptChanges"          "add_ColumnChanged"      "add_ColumnChanging"     "add_Disposed"           "add_Initialized"        "add_RowChanged"
[7] "add_RowChanging"        "add_RowDeleted"         "add_RowDeleting"        "add_TableCleared"       "add_TableClearing"      "add_TableNewRow"
[13] "BeginInit"              "BeginLoadData"          "Clear"                  "Clone"                  "Compute"                "Copy"
[19] "CreateDataReader"       "Dispose"                "EndInit"                "EndLoadData"            "Equals"                 "get_CaseSensitive"
[25] "get_ChildRelations"     "get_Columns"            "get_Constraints"        "get_Container"          "get_DataSet"            "get_DefaultView"
[31] "get_DesignMode"         "get_DisplayExpression"  "get_ExtendedProperties" "get_HasErrors"          "get_IsInitialized"      "get_Locale"
[37] "get_MinimumCapacity"    "get_Namespace"          "get_ParentRelations"    "get_Prefix"             "get_PrimaryKey"         "get_RemotingFormat"
[43] "get_Rows"               "get_Site"               "get_TableName"          "GetChanges"             "GetChanges"             "GetErrors"
[49] "GetHashCode"            "GetObjectData"          "GetService"             "GetType"                "ImportRow"              "Load"
[55] "Load"                   "Load"                   "LoadDataRow"            "LoadDataRow"            "Merge"                  "Merge"
[61] "Merge"                  "NewRow"                 "ReadXml"                "ReadXml"                "ReadXml"                "ReadXml"
[67] "ReadXmlSchema"          "ReadXmlSchema"          "ReadXmlSchema"          "ReadXmlSchema"          "RejectChanges"          "remove_ColumnChanged"
[73] "remove_ColumnChanging"  "remove_Disposed"        "remove_Initialized"     "remove_RowChanged"      "remove_RowChanging"     "remove_RowDeleted"
[79] "remove_RowDeleting"     "remove_TableCleared"    "remove_TableClearing"   "remove_TableNewRow"     "Reset"                  "Select"
[85] "Select"                 "Select"                 "Select"                 "set_CaseSensitive"      "set_DisplayExpression"  "set_Locale"
[91] "set_MinimumCapacity"    "set_Namespace"          "set_Prefix"             "set_PrimaryKey"         "set_RemotingFormat"     "set_Site"
[97] "set_TableName"          "ToString"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"
[103] "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"
[109] "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"               "WriteXml"
[115] "WriteXmlSchema"         "WriteXmlSchema"         "WriteXmlSchema"         "WriteXmlSchema"         "WriteXmlSchema"         "WriteXmlSchema"
[121] "WriteXmlSchema"         "WriteXmlSchema"

$Fields
character(0)

$Properties
[1] "CaseSensitive"      "ChildRelations"     "Columns"            "Constraints"        "Container"          "DataSet"            "DefaultView"        "DesignMode"
[9] "DisplayExpression"  "ExtendedProperties" "HasErrors"          "IsInitialized"      "Locale"             "MinimumCapacity"    "Namespace"          "ParentRelations"
[17] "Prefix"             "PrimaryKey"         "RemotingFormat"     "Rows"               "Site"               "TableName"

**> clrReflect(dv)**
$Methods
[1] "add_Disposed"         "add_Initialized"      "add_ListChanged"      "AddNew"               "BeginInit"            "CopyTo"               "Delete"               "Dispose"
[9] "EndInit"              "Equals"               "Equals"               "Find"                 "Find"                 "FindRows"             "FindRows"             "get_AllowDelete"
[17] "get_AllowEdit"        "get_AllowNew"         "get_ApplyDefaultSort" "get_Container"        "get_Count"            "get_DataViewManager"  "get_DesignMode"       "get_IsInitialized"
[25] "get_Item"             "get_RowFilter"        "get_RowStateFilter"   "get_Site"             "get_Sort"             "get_Table"            "GetEnumerator"        "GetHashCode"
[33] "GetService"           "GetType"              "remove_Disposed"      "remove_Initialized"   "remove_ListChanged"   "set_AllowDelete"      "set_AllowEdit"        "set_AllowNew"
[41] "set_ApplyDefaultSort" "set_RowFilter"        "set_RowStateFilter"   "set_Site"             "set_Sort"             "set_Table"            "ToString"             "ToTable"
[49] "ToTable"              "ToTable"              "ToTable"

$Fields
character(0)

$Properties
[1] "AllowDelete"      "AllowEdit"        "AllowNew"         "ApplyDefaultSort" "Container"        "Count"            "DataViewManager"  "DesignMode"       "IsInitialized"    "Item"            "RowFilter"        "RowStateFilter"   "Site"             "Sort"             "Table"

> To call methods use clrCall(dotNetObject, 'MethodName')
>
> To see properties use clrGet(dotNetObject,'PropertyName')
>
> For example let's work out the number of Rows in the DataTable returned
> from the GetDatatable method:

**> clrCall(dv,'get_Count')**
[1] 2

> Now let's work out the number of columns:

**> clrGet(dataTable,'Columns')**
An object of class "cobjRef"
Slot "clrobj":
<pointer: 0x0ee0f920>

Slot "clrtype":
[1] "System.Data.DataColumnCollection"

**> cols <- clrGet(dataTable,'Columns')**
**> clrReflect(cols)**
$Methods
[1] "Add"                      "Add"                      "Add"                      "Add"                      "Add"                      "add_CollectionChanged"
[7] "AddRange"                 "CanRemove"                "Clear"                    "Contains"                 "CopyTo"                   "CopyTo"
[13] "Equals"                   "get_Count"                "get_IsReadOnly"           "get_IsSynchronized"       "get_Item"                 "get_Item"
[19] "get_SyncRoot"             "GetEnumerator"            "GetHashCode"              "GetType"                  "IndexOf"                  "IndexOf"
[25] "Remove"                   "Remove"                   "remove_CollectionChanged" "RemoveAt"                 "ToString"

$Fields
character(0)

$Properties
[1] "Count"          "IsReadOnly"     "IsSynchronized" "Item"           "Item"           "SyncRoot"

**> clrGet(cols,'Count')**
[1] 26