# A simple Example for Calling a .NET object from R

Tags: .net, r, rclr

I was trying this example from

[Calling .NET/C# from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410528/calling-net-c-from-r?rq=1)

But error is thrown when I am using following code

```
library(rClr)
clrLoadAssembly('c:/path/to/myassembly.dll')
myObj <- clrNew('MyNamespace.MyClass,MyAssemblyName')
clrCall(myObj, 'SayHelloWorld')
```

In following manner:

```
library(rClr) 
clrLoadAssembly('C:\\__\\TstingRLib\\ClassLibrary1\\bin\\Release\\ClassLibrary.dll') 

myObj <- clrNew('System.System.Text,System')
 Type not found: System.System.Text,System Error in clrNew("System.System.Text,System") : Type: System.ArgumentException Message: Could not determine Type from string 'System.System.Text,System' Method: System.Object CreateInstance(System.String, System.Object[]) Stack trace: at Rclr.ClrFacade.CreateInstance(String typename, Object[] arguments) in ___\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2D63Nz\R.INSTALL1f3c2a50350\rClr\src\ClrFacade\ClrFacad‌​e.cs:line 316
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clrLoadAssembly('-----\\Documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\DataConversionSample\\DataConversionSample\\bin\\Release\\DataConversionSample.dll')
> typename = clrGetTypesInAssembly('DataConversionSample')
> typename = "rClr.Samples.DataConversionSample,DataConversionSample"
> obj = clrNew(typename)
> obj
An object of class "cobjRef"
Slot "clrobj":
<pointer: 0x00000000181cb140>

Slot "clrtype":
[1] "rClr.Samples.DataConversionSample,DataConversionSample"
```

Had to do Little more research. Found a tutorial here.

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28480847/

Which helped me get my results:

```
str(clrCallStatic(typename, "GetOneDimStringArray", as.integer(5)))
 chr [1:5] "0" "1" "2" "3" "4"


DateTime to string


clrCallStatic(typename, "DateTimeToString", as.Date('2015-10-26')
+ )
[1] "26/10/15 12:00:00 AM"


Numeric Vector


> str(clrCallStatic(typename, "GetOneDimArray", as.integer(5)))
 num [1:5] 0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4



Rectangular Array

clrCallStatic(typename, "GetRectArray", as.integer(3), as.integer(5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0 0.22 0.44 0.66 0.88
[2,]  1.1 1.32 1.54 1.76 1.98
[3,]  2.2 2.42 2.64 2.86 3.08
```