# Read C# function from .dll file using R

Tags: c#, r

I have a .dll file that contains a function written in C#. How can I extract it and use it using R?

Comment: Or this may be relevant too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410528/calling-net-c-from-r  -- new site is here : https://rclr.codeplex.com/

Comment: I used the `dyn.load( )` function, but the function of the .dll was not loaded. The .dll file was created in the simplest way, so there are no restrictions to access to the content.